# OnActionExecuting equivalent in standard asp.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, webforms, web-parts

Is there an equivalent for MVC.NET's `OnActionExecuting` in standard asp.NET? ?

I thought it would be `Page_Load` since `OnActionExecuting` would be called each time an action is executed (or the page loads). But I'm running into inheritance issues when I try to use Page_Load instead.

Since it is very difficult to make my solution work with a `Page_Load` I'm thinking I might not have the best ... solution.

Any thoughts on whether they are equivalent or close enough?

Background:

I'm converting a piece of an MVC3 application into a standard .NET to wrap in a SharePoint Web Part.

Here's the MVC code I'm trying to translate, as you can see its the user security bits I'm translating:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {

            if (!SiteCacheProvider.ItemCached(enmCacheKey.SiteSetting)) {

                if (filterContext.IsImplementedGeneralPrincipal()) {
                    IUserProfile userProfile = ((IGeneralPrincipal)filterContext.HttpContext.User).UserProfile;

                    SiteCacheProvider.ChangeSiteSetting(userProfile.SiteID);
                }
            }

            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
```

Comment: Do you have an example of the code you have so far?

Comment: @RaimondKuipers my asp.NET code or the MVC code that I'm converting?

Comment: both would be helpfull

Comment: @MyName Take a look at my answer.

Comment: @RaimondKuipers :S thats alot of code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, take on account that *no* Actions are in ASP.NET because the model is different (Event-Based) - There're no methods(actions) which you can decorate with [Action Filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410209%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), it's all about the [Page-Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) events.

Second, In ASP.NET, you may use [HTTP modules](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32475/Asp-net-HTTP-Modules) ([`HttpApplication.BeginRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.beginrequest.aspx) particularly) in order to intercept incoming requests to your application pages by adding your required logic.

From MSDN:

> HTTP Modules use to intercept HTTP requests for modifying or utilize
>   HTTP based requests according to needs like authentication,
>   authorization, session/state management, logging, modifying Response,
>   URL rewriting, Error handling, Caching....

For example:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections;

public class HelloWorldModule : IHttpModule
{
    public string ModuleName
    {
        get { return "HelloWorldModule"; }
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication application)
    {
         application.BeginRequest += (new EventHandler(this.Application_BeginRequest));
         application.EndRequest += (new EventHandler(this.Application_EndRequest));

    }

    private void Application_BeginRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)source;
        HttpContext context = application.Context;
        context.Response.Write("<h1>HelloWorldModule: Beginning of Request</h1><hr>");
    }
    private void Application_EndRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)source;
        HttpContext context = application.Context;
        context.Response.Write("<hr><h1>HelloWorldModule: End of Request</h1>");
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: So I begin request would be similar to on action executing ? I thought Begin request would happen before the action is executing...in an MVC page cycle this is why I thought page load might be more suited. I'm incredibly confused actually. What would OnAuthorization be then?

Comment: I'm guessing its AuthorizeRequest ??

Comment: @MyName The question is what is your goal, is it refer to logging? security?

Comment: Security mainly, I actually think there's a better way to achieve what I want without just blindly translating the code lol. For my purposes, I realized that it doesn't matter if the user is static. Thank you for your help :D I shall mark it as the answer