# Mapping off MVC Life Cycle to Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC Application with some functionality that happens in `OnActionExecuting` method in my BaseController.  I am looking to implement the same functionality into a WebForms Application - I am just wondering what would be the correct Method in Web Forms Life Cycle to put this functionality that would match as closely as possible the OnActionExecuting in MVC

Comment: Related: [OnActionExecuting equivalent in standard asp.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16779970/onactionexecuting-equivalent-in-standard-asp-net)

Answer (score 1):

You can filter in Application_BeginRequest event and in IHTTPModule in ASP.Net webforms.