# Instrument a methods to intercept each method's call

Tags: c#, delegates, refactoring, wrapper, instrumentation

I have the need (a new requirements) to perform few action before and after each method call of a bunch of classes in my project. Is a situation that somewhat reassemble a AOP but what i need is not that complex. I have some BusinessObject (class) and need that each method invokation of my API contained in that BOs will handle logging and authoriting. Because i would avoid to rewrite my codebase i have thougt to wrap my BO, in that way i can "instrument" them, but i am not sure if this is the best approach nor how to deal with some details

Example :

```
    public class TestBo : BaseBo
    {
        private string test = "";

        public TestBo ( string input )
        {
            test = input;
        }

        [PermissionRequired(PermissionAttribute.Login | PermissionAttribute.Read)]
        public void ExampleMethod ()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Run it with " + test);
        }

        public void WriteMessage ( string message )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Write it " + message);
        }
    }



    // IN THE BO Wrapper Class
    public virtual OperationResultDto<object> Execute(Action action, Token token)
    {
        return this.ActionExecute(action, token);
    }

    public virtual OperationResultDto<object> Execute<T1>(Action<T1> action, Token token , T1 param)
    {
        return this.ActionExecute(action, token, param);
    }

    protected virtual OperationResultDto<object> ActionExecute (Delegate action, Token token, params object[] parameters)
    {
        try
        {
            if (action == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("action");

            this._logger.Debug(this.DumpParameters(action, parameters));

            PermissionRequired permission = action.Method.GetCustomAttributes(false).FirstOrDefault(attr => attr is PermissionRequired) as PermissionRequired;

            //TODO : authorization;

            action.DynamicInvoke(parameters);

            this._logger.Debug($"Invokation {action.Method.Name} ended");
            return new OperationResultDto<object>() { Success = true, ReturnData = null };
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            this._logger.Error(err, string.Empty);
            return new OperationResultDto<object>()
            {
                Success = false,
                ErrorText = err.Message,
                Error = err,
                ReturnData = null
            };
        }

        return null;
    }


    //USAGE
    TestBo testBo = new TestBo("Identity");
    testBo.ExampleMethod();

    Token token = new Token(1);

    BoWrapper wrapper = new BoWrapper(testBo);
    wrapper.Execute(testBo.ExampleMethod, token);
    wrapper.Execute<string>(testBo.WriteMessage, token, "Message");
```

That seems to work as intended, but i don't like that :

```
wrapper.Execute<string>.. //I have to repeat method signature each time

public virtual OperationResultDto<object> Execute<T1>(Action<T1>.. 
//I have to write many overload (in BoWrapper) to handle all possible situation.
```

Comment: What kind of project is?

Comment: It's an old ASP.NET project (no MVC), but recently the .net framework version used in compilation was updated to 4.8

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16779970/onactionexecuting-equivalent-in-standard-asp-net

Comment: @Emanuele my scenario is quite different, i have to use the BO in a ASP.NET project but BO are not related to ASP.NET , they are regular C# class that has to be as agnostic as possbile so that i can use the API they expose in different context. The "bheaviour" i need is not an ASP.NET related thing, it's a BO related thing and has to work when i will use that BO in future projects (Winform may be)